# Crop image and retain positioning android

Tags: android

I have two images that are positioned in the same space, effectively overlapping one another.

They are slightly different but identically sized.

I want to be able to crop the top laying image but retain the initial positioning.

So almost like cutting it in half, and keeping the left half in place, which would perfectly overlap the underlaying image.

The following is the code I have, just two `ImageView`'s within a `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/level_off">

    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/level_on">

    </ImageView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any ideas? I've done my best to explain what I mean! Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of what result you're getting, and what you're expecting?

Comment: remove layout gravity from your 2nd image view.

Comment: Or perhaps use __android:layout_gravity="top|right"__ instead of 
        __android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"__, on the second image view.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an programmatic approach by inheriting ImageView and override `onDraw()`, doing so will also save you an extra layout group.

In `onDraw()`you have to:

1. obtain the imageMatrix from your original image
2. alter the canvas to left/right half of your original size
3. draw the second image in that altered canvas with the same matrix as the original image

I've done a similar thing and theoretically it should work for your case as well.